# Is using map(...) in Python 3 Pythonic (compared to a loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert a list of string representations of tuples, such as:

```
["(279, 256000, '.m4a')", "(217, 256000, '.m4a')", "(174, 128000, '.mp3')"]
```

into a list of tuples, such as:

```
[(279, 256000, '.m4a'), (217, 256000, '.m4a'), (174, 128000, '.mp3')]
```

This seems to be the most concise (and clear) way to do it

```
recs = ... # loaded from text file
data  = map(eval, recs)
```

However, Ive seen a posting [Python course - lambda](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_lambda.php)
that seems to imply *map()* may not be good python or may become deprecated.

The alternative would seem to be something like the more verbose (and hence slightly less clear):

```
data = []
for r in recs:
    data += [eval(r)]
```

Which is more pythonic?

Answer (score 8):

`map` is fine when used with a named function; it’s when you use it with an inline lambda that a list comprehension or generator expression becomes cleaner. `eval`, on the other hand, is not really fine. Consider [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead.

```
import ast

data = map(ast.literal_eval, recs)
```

Also, `map` returns an iterable (in Python 3); if you want a list, you’ll have to call `list` on the result.

```
data = list(map(ast.literal_eval, recs))
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance (fairly new to Python) , but why is eval 'not really fine'?   
As proof of my newness, I havent yet come across ast - will check that out, thanks for the tip.
...
I suspected the loop was not 'pythonic', thanks for the alternative.

Comment: @RFlack: `eval` can execute arbitrary code, so it’s not safe to use on user input. Even if you think that doesn’t apply to your case, related security vulnerabilities have a habit of sneaking in, so it’s best to use a more restrictive equivalent if possible.

Comment: ah that makes sense.  in this case the data are 'safe' being written by (my) program, not user input.  But I take your point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion using `map` is a nice functional solution, but can be seen as a redundant language feature since generators were added. On the other hand your example that iterates over the array and concatenates to a list is *not* Pythonic.

Some Pythonic alternatives to `map`:

```
# a list comprehesion
[ast.literal_eval(r) for r in recs]
```

or

```
# a generator expression
(ast.literal_eval(r) for r in recs)
```

or

```
# a generator function
def mapYourData(recs):
  for r in recs:
    yield ast.literal_eval(r)
```

Don't forget to `import ast`

EDIT: as @minitech pointed out you shold use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval`.